# How to add Loki to the project kube-prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

i'm new to Helm and i want to add Loki to the kube-prometheus project but i can't figure out how to do it. but i have run the kube-prometheus stack with helm and Loki with helm and i have added the Loki datasource to grafana dashbord and it worked.

but i can't figure out in code how to do it and add Loki to the stack.

this is the kube-prometheus stack : https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus

Comment: Which steps have you followed so far ? What is your cloud provider, provide more details about your environment. If you are using specific tutorial for setup paste links.

Comment: for the environment i'm using minikube , and this is where i found a possible solution but i could not understand it https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/555.